# When would I use append and when would I use insert?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

I already know that `a` and `i` makes the cursor one space to the right and left respectively, but when would I use `i` to edit a file? Is there some special circumstance that makes insertion  mode more useful than appending the text?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really tell what you mean by `insert` here, can you please clarify? One reason why you need an `a` command is that you can't put the cursor after the last character of the line, so you can't really use `i` to start Insert mode after the current end of the line. (An exception being an empty line.) But not sure whether that's what you mean...

Comment: do you mean `:insert`?  like the ed command?

Comment: sorry, i just edited it. i meant like `a` and `i` for editing a file (insertion and appending)

Comment: Vim has many commands (almost) duplicating each other. This is just normal.

Comment: So something like `b` and `B` are exactly the same right?

Comment: `b` and `B` are different. Read help topics.

Comment: you use whatever you need for your particular situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if you can edit where your cursor is or if you need to move your cursor.

For example, you have the following:

```
Your cursor here
      V
[...] hell [...]
```

and want to change `hell` into `shell`, you'd use `i`, to be in the good place directly (rather than using append, and move the cursor with the arrow key while in insert mode).

However, if you have the following:

```
Your cursor here
      V
[...] hell [...]
```

And want to change `hell` into `hello`, you'd do `e` to go at the end of the word, and then press `a` to start editing after the last `l` to add the missing letter.

Comment: Well, I would press `I` and `A` out of habit given the beginning and end of line, but nice demonstration.

Comment: Agreed. The example was more like with potential context around, I'll update the answer.